# Django admin overwriting fieldsets

Tags: django-admin

Suppose we have one class in the model from which several other classes are inherited. Now we define also an admin class to control the layout in the admin interface.

We can make all other admin classes inherite (just as we did in the model), but how can we overwrite the fieldsets to add some new values?

Example:

in model file:

```
class A(models.Model):
  field1 = models.TextField(..)
  field2 = models.TextField(..)

class B(A):
  field3 = models.TextField(..)
```

in admin file:

```
class A_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (( 'field1', 'field2'))
        }),
    )

class B_Admin(A_Admin):
    pass # here I notice that it takes the fields from A_admin, I would like to add my field 3 without rewriting the fieldsets 

admin.site.register(A, A_Admin)
admin.site.register(B, B_Admin)
```

the resulting fieldsets would be :

```
(
        (None, {
            'fields': (( 'field1', 'field2'))
        }),

        ('Specific to B', {
            'fields': ('field3')
        }),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a neat solution but it should do what you want.

```
class A_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
            (None, {'fields': ['field1', 'field2']}),
    ]

class B_Admin(A_Admin):
    fieldsets = [
             ('Specific to B', {'fields': ['field3', 'field4']}),
    ]
    fieldsets.insert(0, A_Admin.fieldsets[0])
```